# How to find if an llvm::Instruction lies within flow control?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

With LLVM I am trying to find out if an Instruction is present within flow control (if/switch/for) etc and I have to do this at the IR level. A pseudo-code is something like this as below.

```
if cond
    inst
endif
```

I am looking at the SCC of the function but I am not sure how to deduce for sure if an instruction does exist within a flow control or not.

Taking the example from the Kaleidoscope example for this IR.

```
declare double @foo()

declare double @bar()

define double @baz(double %x) {
entry:
  %ifcond = fcmp one double %x, 0.000000e+00
  %0 = call double @foo()
  br i1 %ifcond, label %then, label %else

then:       ; preds = %entry
  %calltmp = call double @foo()
  br label %ifcont

else:       ; preds = %entry
  %calltmp1 = call double @bar()
  br label %ifcont

ifcont:     ; preds = %else, %then
  %iftmp = phi double [ %calltmp, %then ], [ %calltmp1, %else ]
  %1 = call double @foo()
  ret double %iftmp
}
```

So in the above IR, lets say I want to find out all the calls to the function foo. So in the entry block we have one call with %0 and one in the then: block we have another call to foo and the last one in the ifcont: block.

So the question is that although the call in the then: block falls in the code generated from if block, how do I deduce that ? i.e. entry block & ifcont block will be executed, however the then: block won't be necessarily executed depending on the condition.

Could someone give me some pointers ?
Thanks

Edit: Giving some more thought, Dominator trees might help in determining this but I don't have an algorithm for this yet.

Comment: Couldn't you just iterate over the instructions of a basic block as described here: http://www.llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterating-over-the-instruction-in-a-basicblock ?

Comment: Iterating over the blocks won't give us the answer for this. The reason being as in the example above, the then: block might or might not be executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a definition of instruction post-domination [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominator_%28graph_theory%29):

> Analogous to the definition of dominance above, a node z is said to
>   post-dominate a node n if all paths to the exit node of the graph
>   starting at n must go through z.

It seems to me that in your case you're looking for calls that post-dominate the first instruction in the function. Such calls, by definition of post-domination, must be reached on every path from the first instruction. Is this what you need?

You can run the `DominatorTree` pass which seems to support post-domination analysis.

Comment: Thanks for answering this Eli. This is exactly what I want. So basically what I am planning to do from your answer is to find all basic blocks which are not post-dominated by the entry block. If any block is not post-dominated, then I could search that block to see if I can find the instruction I am interested in. Thus if an instruction is found in a non-post-dominated block for the entry then that instruction could be considered to be inside a flow control (from a higher level). Does this sound reasonable ?

Comment: @ssarangi: I think you would rather look for blocks that post-dominate the entry block. This means that all paths from the entry to exit go through such blocks, which is what you want. Then look for your calls in such blocks.